# Parameter #1 $json of function json_decode expects string, string|false given

Tags: php

```
const POST_DB = 'db\\posts.json';

function getPosts($return_assoc = 0)
{
    $aa = file_get_contents("db/posts.json");
    $posts = json_decode($aa);
    return $posts;
}
```

> Parameter #1 $json of function json_decode expects string,
>   string|false given.

Comment: explain better your problem and how you tried to solve it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents() function gives back FALSE in case of an error.

It could be that the file is not present at the given path. Other case could be that the server process does not have permission to access the file.

Try this:

```
function getPosts($return_assoc = 0)
{
    $aa = file_get_contents("db/posts.json");
    if ( $aa === FALSE )
    {
         //TODO: error handling
         return FALSE;
    }
    $posts = json_decode($aa);
    return $posts;
}
```